# Cesium JS Save Camera Position

Tags: 3d, data-visualization, cesiumjs

I'm thinking of saving a camera position (specifically rotation) so changing back and forth between 2D and 3D will always go back to my last viewed position in 3D. What is the best way to do this?

I would also like to save it as a cookie or in local storage so that the user would go straight into that saved view on the page with Cesium from other pages (which may not be the US).

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend just creating a simple JS object and storing the properties of the camera before you switch views.  Then just store it into localStorage.  I find store.js a really useful wrapper for browser agnostic local storage.

If you need more help I can come up with an example later tonight.

```
    var camera = $scope.viewer.scene.camera;
    var store = {
      position: camera.position.clone(),
      direction: camera.direction.clone(),
      up: camera.up.clone(),
      right: camera.right.clone(),
      transform: camera.transform.clone(),
      frustum: camera.frustum.clone()
    };
```

Comment: Hi @Mike LP, I found this helpful to save and restore the camera settings, have you any clue on how to get world coordinate position (longitude, latitude) directly from the camera setting? I tried something like: ``` Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(amera.position.clone().x, amera.position.clone().y))``` but seems the wrong approach. Thanks for any help.

Comment: off the top of my head, no, but I'll play around with it this weekend

Comment: To get long/lat from the camera position, do the following: var camera = viewer.scene.camera;
      var currentCartesian = camera.position.clone()
      var currentCartographic = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianToCartographic(currentCartesian);    // then you can use: Cesium.Math.toDegrees(currentCartographic.longitude) etc

Answer (score 2):

Based off of [Mike LP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23550082/1599699)'s answer:

```js
let undoCamera = {
    position: this.camera.position.clone(),
    direction: this.camera.direction.clone(),
    up: this.camera.up.clone()
};
this.camera.position = undoCamera.position;
this.camera.direction = undoCamera.direction;
this.camera.up = undoCamera.up;
```

This works for me, at least in 3D and Columbus modes.

You can also do the same with `frustum`, if needed.

https://www.cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Camera.html

Answer (score 0):

// Get the current camera view extent (rectangle)
const cameraExtentRectangle = viewer.camera.computeViewRectangle();

```
// Check if the camera extent is valid (not zero or near-zero)
if (Cesium.defined(cameraExtentRectangle)) {
  const west = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cameraExtentRectangle.west);
  const south = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cameraExtentRectangle.south);
  const east = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cameraExtentRectangle.east);
  const north = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cameraExtentRectangle.north);

  // Create a GeoJSON Polygon feature from the extent
  const geoJSONFeature = {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {},
    geometry: {
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: [
        [
          [west, north],
          [east, north],
          [east, south],
          [west, south],
          [west, north], // Closing the polygon
        ],
      ],
    },
  };

  // Convert the GeoJSON feature to a JSON string
  const geoJSONString = JSON.stringify(geoJSONFeature);

  console.log(geoJSONString);
} else {
  console.error("Invalid camera extent: Cannot compute the view extent.");
}
```

We can test the geoJson polygon using this site:
https://geojson.io/